# Convert an __int64 to a std::u32string

Tags: java, c++, servlets, casablanca, utf-32

I am writing a native Windows C++ application which uses the Casablanca REST API.  I am trying to pass an integer value from the C++ application to a Java servlet which will be running in the cloud.  When making a `GET` REST call, the Casablanca API expects me to use an `std::u32string` to store a query parameter.  It is somewhat intuitive to me why one would want to use UTF-32 encoding to ensure that every type of character can be supported.  What is not intuitive to me is how to go about doing this conversion.

Here is my current code:

```
__int64 queryID = 12345689;               // the integer to pass
std::stringstream stream;
stream << queryID;
std::string queryID_utf8(stream.str());   // the integer as a UTF-8 string
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> convert;
std::u32string queryID_utf32 = convert.from_bytes(queryID_utf8); // UTF-32 string

http_client client(U("http://localhost:8080/MyJavaWebApp"));
uri_builder builder(U("/getContent"));
builder.append_query(U("queryID"), queryID_utf32.c_str());
client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string()) // etc.
```

I am also not entirely certain how I should be handling things on the Java side once I receive this UTF-32 encoded string.  Any expert C++ advice will be greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

I used `wchar` and `swprintf` etc. when I was working with Casablanca in C++.

```
pplx::task<MPS_Request::ProcessResult*> MPS_Request::ProcessCreate (ProcessResult * processData)
{
    http_request request (methods::GET);
    request.set_request_uri (L"?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content");

    http_client client (L"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php");

    // Make the request and asynchronously process the response
    return client.request (request).then ([processData](http_response response)
    {
        // Grab the status code
        processData->statusCodeTSG = response.status_code ();

        if (processData->statusCodeTSG == HTTP_RET_OK)
        {
            // Read the stream into a string
            auto bodyStream = response.body ();
            container_buffer<string> stringBuffer;

            bodyStream.read_to_end (stringBuffer).then ([stringBuffer, processData](size_t bytesRead)
            {
                // Allocate and copy
                const string &line = stringBuffer.collection ();
                const char * output = line.c_str ();

                processData->resultStreamTSG = new char [strlen (output) + 1];
                strcpy_s (processData->resultStreamTSG, (strlen (output) + 1), output);
            })
            .wait ();
        }

        return processData;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, my situation is that I need to dynamically pass a query parameter to the Casablanca API, which demands a `u32string`.  In your example, you hard-coded a wide character string into the URI.

Comment: My version was just a test but I could happily set dynamic queries with `swprintf` into a `wchar` array - it's not much use otherwise ;). Looking through the Casablanca source I built against it is just `typdef`ing `string_t`,  which is the generic string type `uri_builder` takes, to `std::wstring` anyway. I guess your version is different? Mine is over a year old now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `swprintf`, as was correctly suggested by @CharlieScott-Skinner in his thoughtful answer.  The trick here is to use the formatting parameter `%I64u` to ensure that the `__int64` will be handled correctly.

As a general comment, note that this is more of a C-style approach to solving this problem rather than using the C++ `string` classes.  That being said, the `string` classes were created to make our lives easier, and if there are use cases where they do not help, then we should be free to try other things.

```
__int64 queryID = 9223372036854775807;                    // largest supported value
wchar_t query_buffer[30];                                 // give enough space for largest
swprintf(query_buffer, 30, L"%I64u", queryID);            //     possible value
web::json::value result = RestDownload(query_buffer);     // call helper function

// my helper method returns JSON which is then processed elsewhere
pplx::task<json::value> RestDownload(const wchar_t* queryID) {
    http_client client(U("http://localhost:8080/MyJavaWebApp"));
    uri_builder builder(U("/getContent"));
    builder.append_query(U("queryID"), queryID);          // this is OK

    return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string()).then([](http_response response) {
        if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK) {
            return response.extract_json();
        }

        // Handle error cases, for now return empty json value... 
        return pplx::task_from_result(json::value());
    });
}
```

Comment: `swprintf()` formats a `wchar_t[]` buffer.  `wchar_t` is 16bit (UTF-16) on some systems (most notably, Windows) but is 32bit (UTF-32) on other platforms. AFAIK, `std::u32string` does not have a constructor that accepts `wchar_t*` as input, it expects `char32_t*` instead, so you cannot pass a `wchar_t*` where a `char32_t*` is expected, unless your compiler is defining `char32_t` as just a typedef for `wchar_t` when it is 32bit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you answer my question formally?  The Casablanca API expects an `std::u32string`.  How can I convert an `__int64` to `std::u32string` ?

Comment: You already know the answer to that, because it is in your original question - use `std::stringstream` (I would suggest `std::ostringstream` instead) with `std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>>` to convert a UTF-8 string to a UTF-32 string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the comments.  Years of working with Java have left me in a clueless state about C++.  Big thanks to Jay Gosling and Sun for that ^ ^.